# AGs with async commit or Zerto for DR to a secondary data center?

Tags: availability-groups, clustering

We have several two node AGs configured across two data centers for DR.  They're all async commit due to the lag, and the company is ok with minimal data loss.  We're considering replacing the AGs with Zerto replication of each primary sql instance, which would also incur some data loss.  We used Zerto during our datacenter moves to move powered off sql instances to their new datacenter, but sql services don't shut down gracefully and allow a final replication in a DR scenario. :-)

Zerto takes Windows clustering, quorum, file share witnesses out of the equation, but it has its own application level vs. crash level consistency issues.  Any thoughts or recommendations?  Thanks!